# Angular 5 Array does not get refreshed after pushing

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-observable

I created Mat Dialog box which provides some fields to fill. When hit the create button on dialog, it pushes ticket to array in ticket service.

After creating ticket, dialog box automatically closes but I can not see the ticket which has been added by dialog box. 
The main page shows all tickets but I can not see my new ticket among them.First I supposed I overwrited ticket service providers somehow, but it is not releated with it.
The main logic is when you create ticket with dialog box, ,it needs to show main page after closing dialog box.

Please contact me if you more info about program or code

The all Code is on https://github.com/Erkanerkisi/IssueTracking

Comment: Giving your code isn't the same as making a MCVE. Could you make one on stackblitz ?

Comment: i think you have to get tickets again after adding new one, you are creating shallow copy in the tickets service

Comment: @trichetriche sorry, i could not add npm module libraries due to have many files in it. I will try on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I solved this issue with BehaviorSubject<>();

I converted "tickets array" as observables.

You can check from my github link.

Thank you very much for responses.

Erkan